# semantic logging does not log the updated event source message in Out-Of-Process

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

I am using Semantic Logging Out-Of-Process in my application. I have created an eventsource class as shown below

```
[EventSource(Name = "SemanticLoggingOutOfProcessEventSource")]
public class SampleEventSource : EventSource
{

    public class Keywords
    {
        public const EventKeywords Page = (EventKeywords)1;
        public const EventKeywords DataBase = (EventKeywords)2;
        public const EventKeywords Diagnostic = (EventKeywords)4;
        public const EventKeywords Perf = (EventKeywords)8;
    }

    public class Opcodes
    {
        public const EventOpcode Start = (EventOpcode)20;
        public const EventOpcode Finish = (EventOpcode)21;
        public const EventOpcode Error = (EventOpcode)22;
        public const EventOpcode Starting = (EventOpcode)23;

        public const EventOpcode QueryStart = (EventOpcode)24;
        public const EventOpcode QueryFinish = (EventOpcode)25;
        public const EventOpcode QueryNoResults = (EventOpcode)26;

        public const EventOpcode CacheQuery = (EventOpcode)27;
        public const EventOpcode CacheUpdate = (EventOpcode)28;
        public const EventOpcode CacheHit = (EventOpcode)29;
        public const EventOpcode CacheMiss = (EventOpcode)30;
    }

    public class Tasks
    {
        public const EventTask Page = (EventTask)1;
        public const EventTask DBQuery = (EventTask)2;
        public const EventTask Application = (EventTask)3;            
    }

    [Event(1, Message = "Method1 Starting.", Opcode = Opcodes.Starting, Task = Tasks.DBQuery, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Perf)]
    public void Method1Starting() { if (this.IsEnabled()) this.WriteEvent(1); }

    [Event(2, Message = "Method1 Ending.", Opcode = Opcodes.Finish, Task = Tasks.DBQuery, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Perf)]
    public void Method1Ending() { if (this.IsEnabled()) this.WriteEvent(2); }

    [Event(3, Message = "Method2 Starting.", Opcode = Opcodes.Starting, Task = Tasks.DBQuery, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Perf)]
    public void Method2Starting() { if (this.IsEnabled()) this.WriteEvent(3); }

    [Event(4, Message = "Method2 Ending.", Opcode = Opcodes.Finish, Task = Tasks.DBQuery, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Perf)]
    public void Method2Ending() { if (this.IsEnabled()) this.WriteEvent(4); }

    public static readonly SampleEventSource outOfProcessLog = new SampleEventSource();                
}
```

I set the eventsource name in the packages\EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Service.2.0.1406.1\tools\SemanticLogging-svc.xml. I started the Semantic Service and ran the application. The log was written to the "packages\EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Service.2.0.1406.1\tools\SemanticLogging-svc.runtime.log" file. I have the following issues:

1. Whenever i make a change to the Message attribute ( suppose i change the "Method1 Starting." to "Method1 Started."). The log is written again as "Method1 Starting." instead of "Method1 Started.". Why? The only way i could achieve this is to stop the service and change the EventSource Name everytime there is an update to Message attribute, which is very painful. Is there any other way to achieve this without changing the EventSource name?
2. Is it possible to log messages to any other log file instead of logging to SemanticLogging-svc.runtime.log?
3. I could only create EventOpcode starting from 20. Wont i be able to start EventOpcodes from 1 similar to Tasks?

Comment: You need to bump the version number of the EventAttribte when you make changes.  If you omit this parameter, the default is 0, and it will not recognize changes.